# Restart an instance of Azure Cloud Service using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-cli

Is it possible to restart an instance of an Azure Cloud Service through the [Azure CLI](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli)?

Azure CLI command reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/). I have seen options for restarting a vm, a vmss, a function app, a service fabric node and a web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** It is not possible to restart an instance of an Azure Cloud Services through Azure CLI.

As Walter said, you can use Azure CLI 1.0 to create and manage Azure Cloud Service, but you cannot restart an instance.

You may check the available options for Azure Cloud Service with Azure CLI 1.0:

[Azure CLI Options for Cloud Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrboI.jpg)

You may use Azure PowerShell to restart an instance of an Cloud Services:

PS C:> ReSet-AzureRoleInstance -ServiceName "**MySvc01**" -Slot "**Staging**" -InstanceName "**MyWebRole_IN_0**" -Reboot

Comment: Accepted as it provides a more concrete example and it actually mentions that you _cannot_ reboot an instance even through Azure CLI 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to restart an instance of an Azure Cloud Service
>   through the Azure CLI?

Based on my knowledge, it is not possible.

Azure Cloud Service is a Classic mode service. However, Azure CLI 2.0 is optimized for managing and administering Azure resources from the command line, and for building automation scripts that work against the Azure Resource Manager. ASM/Classic mode is not supported in the Azure CLI 2.0.   Please refer to this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-azure-cli-2-preview/).

[Azure Cli 1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cli-install-nodejs) supports ASM mode and Cloud Service.

Comment: Thank you. Will circle back after I give Azure CLI 1.0 a try.